# Dynamic Height in react-native horizontal Flatlist

Tags: android, image, react-native, height, react-native-flatlist

For my project, I have to show posts so I have a vertical flatlist for the posts and inside each post, there is another flatlist that is horizontal and shows the images for that post.

It is working but my issue is how to make flatlist adjust to size changes for each image that is there in the horizontal flatlist. It takes the height of the maximum one and doesn't readjust for each image.